# Add special character in keyname in Json, while sending json to api using retrofit Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I am using retrofit for api call and Moshi, and for request one of key name is having a special character @ and when making the request its getting removed by Moshi or retrofit and getting missing key response from server is there any way to pass @ or special characters in keyname ?

```
@Json(name = "@Keyname") val Keyname: String,
```

Comment: Is this `@Json(name = "@Keyname")` pseudo-code? Because Gson does not have an annotation called `@Json`. If possible, please also provide a minimal reproducible example showing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for sending special character in keyname of a json we can use it like this using Moshi

```
@field:Json(name = "@Keyname") val keyname: String,
```

// it will create a json like this

```
{
"@keyname":"value"
}
```